# Classifiers on floating point numbers

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I have dataset with 1 feature and N samples. I am trying to predict the below "target" column from "feature" column. All ​of the values are floating point numbers between 1 and 4: e.g 1.2, 2.2, etc

```
target     feature    
0.0          0.0
6.0          8.0
7.2          1.0
2.3          2.0
1.1          5.0
5.0          1.0
0.0          0.0
0.0          1.0
0.0          0.0
```

I am working with scikit-learn. Error I am getting is (with either a DecisionTreeClassifier, or RandomForest):

```
ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

I am unable to get any classifier to work on this data, unless I convert them to strings or integers.​ However, I need to be able to predict the​se​ decimal points​, so that is not an option.

​I am a beginner at machine learning, and want to make sure that I am not making any stupid mistakes in the process.

- First off: is it correct to convert these floats to strings and simply run a classifier on those strings? (e.g, randomforest... ) What would be the caveats for this method?
- What are some classifie​rs that I can run on floats?
- Should I instead be using regressors?

​Thanks!​

Comment: Could you post a short snippet of your code and data? You question seems unclear to me.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what libraries you're using or anything.  Exactly what problems did you encounter using floats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are mistaking classification problem for regression one. If the final labels that you want to predict are also float values, then I guess you are mistaking your regression problem for a classification one.

Also you can't simply just convert float to strings, because

- Convert them to string would convert them to categorical values, and this would be completely wrong, since the underlying data patterns would simply be lost.
- Also, float values are numerical values, which are supposed to belong to some sort of sequence. Changing them to string would essential lead to loss of this info in the conversion process.
- Also, most classifiers convert categorical variable to some sort of encoding (like one-hot encoding). Converting float values to string and then to another encoding would introduce unnecessary noise (besides being algorithmically wrong)

Almost all the classifiers can work on Floating data. However, they might be not working in your case because it is a regression problem and not a classification one.
Here are implementations of [K-means](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_iris.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-cluster-iris-py), [SVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classification_probability.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-classification-plot-classification-probability-py) and [Random forest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_iris.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-forest-iris-py) on iris dataset which has floating data, but the is a classification problem.

Try using any regressor and you will find some success with your problem